# C# WPF manage treeview item templates

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, datatemplate, treeviewitem

Maybe this is quiet simple question but I have a problems with construction of a template for my treeview. I have some classes:

```
public class A //main class
{
    public B sth { get; set; }
    public C sthelse { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        this.sth = new B(1000, "sth");
        this.sthelse = new C();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public D sth { get; set; }

    public B(ulong data, String abc)
    {
        this.sth = new D(data, abc);
    }
}

public class D
{
    public ulong data { get; private set; }
    public String abc { get; private set; }

    public D(ulong data, String abc)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.abc = abc;
    }
}
```

And my question is how can I put it into treeview. I was testing HierarchicalDataTemplate but problem is that it have to be bound to collection. Any ideas how to create treeview like this:

- A

  - B

    - D

      - data
      - abc
  - C

Is it possible?

I am using this code:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource phy}" />

<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="d">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- Maybe there should be pairs property - value, maybe grid or whatever -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=data}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=abc}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="b" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sth}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=d}">
                <TextBlock Text="D" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!-- Cant bind also attribute C -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="phy" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sth}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=b}">
            <TextBlock Text="PHY" />                
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In code is:

```
public ObservableCollection<A> data { get; private set; }
```

And in constructor:

```
data = new ObservableCollection<A>();
treeView1.DataContext = data;
data.Add(new A());
```

Comment: How are you planning to initialize your classes ? Look into this example...must help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: First of all the problem with ItemSource Binding is that I cant bind both of them together so class A dont have B and C as childs.

Comment: I don't see the class C. Also the following lines would not compile.this.B = new B(1000, "sth");
this.C = new C(); this.D = new D(data, abc);

Comment: Sorry for that I checked and fixed it cause I did it on knee. Class C may be any class does not depend. All the time it put only PHY nad nothing else. I think that problem is in HDT ItemsSource cause it isnt a collection but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: This is the definition of public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }, i.e. all the ItemsSources you declared such as ItemsSource="{Binding Path=sth}" has to be of type Ienumerable, a collection as you said.

Comment: And what I can do if it is not? Are there any possibilities how to do it ?

Comment: Even though you might have single items in each objects, create Observable or List of items for every objects you want to bind as ItemsSource. Saying that what you can do as you did for A, var listofB = new ObservableCollection<B>(); listofB.Add(new B()); Then use ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listofB}". Something in this line.

Comment: Sure. But using collections for single item is quiet hard code I think. Maybe solution could be to implement function that will add treeviewitems as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemsSource` property values *must* be `IEnumerable`. There's no way to avoid this. You can expose `IEnumerables` in a very simple way such as below, but I would recommend a better object model than this. You can take these classes and bind the `ItemsSource` properties of the tree and the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to this new `Nodes` property.

```
public class A //main class
{
    public B sth { get; set; }
    public C sthelse { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        this.sth = new B(1000, "sth");
        this.sthelse = new C();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            yield return B;
            yield return C;
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    public D sth { get; set; }

    public B(ulong data, String abc)
    {
        this.sth = new D(data, abc);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            yield return D;
        }
    }
}

public class D
{
    public ulong data { get; private set; }
    public String abc { get; private set; }

    public D(ulong data, String abc)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            yield return data;
            yield return abc;
        }
    }
}
```